# 404 Page not found using form submission

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

In localhost all is okay.

But I have a hosting where in the /public_html/site folder I have the main WordPress site. I have another PHP site which has no htaccess in /public_html/site/BETA.

You can login here: http://yoursocialtool.com/BETA/login.php
User: stack
Password: overflow
Now the problem is when I am trying to logout after login using a form submission to the same page like as http://yoursocialtool.com/BETA/dashboard.php it says:

> 404 Page not found!

But if I directly put the url in the browser address bar http://yoursocialtool.com/BETA/dashboard.php then its loading fine without any 404 error.

The .htaccess in /public_html:

```
RewriteOptions inherit

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yoursocialtool.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.yoursocialtool.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !site/
RewriteRule (.*) /site/$1 [L]
```

The .htaccess in /public_html/site:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /site/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /site/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Here is the codes which I am using in my dashboard.php:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','On');
ini_set('error_log','error.log');
require("config.inc.php");
require("__require_login.php");
require_once("_isconnected.php");
if (isAppLoggedIn()){
    require("_dashboard.html.php");
} else {
    echo ($msg);
    ?>
    <script>
window.location = "./login.php?from=dashboard&location=";
window.location.assign("./login.php?from=dashboard&location=assign");
    </script>
    <?php
}
?>
```

And the problem which I am facing is that the code is not executing JavaScript redirect in the server after login. Actually its not getting the dashboard.php after I am submitting the logout request although it seems to have logout successfully. I am handling the logout action in the dashboard.php also. Seems to be that the /public_html/site/index.php is handling it only after the logout submission.

N.B: My localhost have only the part of the site under /public_html/site/BETA. So the localhost does not have any htaccess or wordpress.

Comment: Obviously the file represented by `http://myrootsite.com/BETA/dashboard.php` does not exist, hence the 404. What is your question? Keep in mind that you can't inherit up the tree, just downwards. So as you ask here, you're obviously missing to understand the [`inherit` rewrite option](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteoptions) and also the scope of this website, see http://stackoverflow.com/help to learn about which kind of questions are OK to ask here and how to formulate a good, concrete, programming centric quesiton (which are normally accepted).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a support request configuring a third party software, here namely Apache HTTPD.

Comment: I have asked about Specific programming problems/Coding techniques. So its not a off-topic.

Comment: And http://example.com/BETA/dashboard.php is available through address bar but not through form submission. The actual link is yoursocialtool.com/BETA/dashboard.php. I am updating the link in question.

Comment: Don't waste too much time. Your error seems clear: Either you access `/site/BETA/dashboard.php` or you will get a 404. That's how you've configured your webserver.

Comment: Please see the htaccess in /public_html. From here its accessible by not using /site/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34322/discussion-between-sazzad-hossain-khan-and-hakre)

Comment: @hakre How is this question off-topic?  Apache HTTPD is a common tool used by web programmers.  It has over 27,000 tagged questions.

Comment: @BLaZuRE: So what? How does that make it on-topic? Please see the close reasons that have been chosen decently by the Stackoverflow community.

Comment: @hakre Apparently a question that generally covers "software tools commonly used by programmers" is on-topic for Stack Overflow according to the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) you linked.  Also, based on the close reasons, I see no reason to close this question as off-topic.

Comment: @BLaZuRE: Please take the minor but distinct difference in the wording to the yours quoted similar close-reason *"Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools **used primarily for programming**. You may be able to get help on Super User."* (highlight by me). The tools quoted here - .htaccess - are ***used primarily for webserver configuration***, not programming. It's probably worth to be extremely picky here as the OP has missed the opportunity to outline exactly why his example *should* work.

Comment: @Sazzad Hossain Khan: Please see the edits I did, see the placeholders and fill them as you deem necessary (or remove them), this might improve your question even in case it get's moved to some other Q&A site.

Comment: @hakre I agree with you, but note that Apache configuration questions are [officially on-topic on SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39063/mod-rewrite-questions-getting-migrated-to-sf)

Comment: @hakre I didn't want to ramble on here or chat, so I stopped commenting since it's **not relevant to answering this question**.  Based on your comment, an Android phone is primarily used for telephony & as a mobile computer, however, it is also relevant to programming for mobile developers.  There are also certain ways you need to configure an Android device in order to get a mobile application to work.

Comment: Please check now. I have put username and password. Try to logout after login. Then you can see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the site to a subdomain. After that I see 500 error with 404.
I have found out the solution consulting with the Apache system administrator. They had showed me that there was error in the log like below:

```
malformed header from script. Bad header=
```

Then I found that the server is not supporting the redirection in server side php script. Then I disable the redirection in server and now its working fine. I used JavaScript redirect.

```
<?php
//header('Location: http://www.example.com/');//Use JavaScript to redirect instead. Comment it out
exit;
?>
```

If someone must need the redirection then may try using the construct `exit;` just after the header declaration. Otherwise use JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

> In localhost all is okay.

Only because it works on localhost it must not need to work everywhere. This is why it is inherently important that your development version of the server-configuration is close (if not identical) to the server-configuration you deploy it to later on.

For that use [virtualization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtualization) and try to reproduce the 404 on your localhost then.

Getting the same behavior on both ends is a first sane check to do in troubleshooting the issue. From the current information you provide in your question this is the best suggestion I can give.

The short answer is: The configuration between both systems differ. Take care you are able to use the same configuration on both systems which includes not only configuration directives but also the same version of all softwares involved, for example the same version of the webserver, the same operating system and the same version of PHP (albeit PHP does not seem to be the issue here).

Comment: Can you please try to login and logout? Then you can see the problem. I have said about the login info.

Comment: @Sazzad Hossain Khan: Please provide me access to your localhost computer where you are not able to reproduce the problem. I fully trust you that you are able to trigger the error on the public system as you have outlined it. I don't need to retry it there as it differs from your localhost, so reproducing on localhost is the key to get this solved. Please take note: I only accept access to public computers. If this localhost is a private configuration, this requires it doing under contract to keep your privacy and which allows me to keep this on a professional level.

Comment: I have added some code in the edit. Please check it. And can you connect in my private computer through TeamViewer? And if yes then where should I send you the access?

Comment: @SazzadHossainKhan: Are you okay with paying four hours of support upfront flat and non-refundable (ca. 268 EUR). If not, please don't ask me personally. If yes, I'm happy to help you if you provide me an email address for further contact.

Comment: Sorry @hakre: Its more than the whole project budget. So I am unable. However thanks to you.